# Exponentials of profunctors

Tags: ct.category-theory, profunctors

Suppose $f:B\to A$ is an [exponentiable functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponentiable+functor), so that pullback $f^\ast$ has a right adjoint $\Pi_f$.  Then $f\times \mathbf{2} : B\times \mathbf{2} \to A\times \mathbf{2}$ is also exponentiable, and a category over $B\times \mathbf{2}$ is the same as two categories $C_0$ and $C_1$ over $B$ and a "profunctor $C_0$ ⇸ $C_1$ over $B$" (you can regard this as a definition of "profunctor over $B$" if you want); thus $\Pi_f$ extends to a functor from profunctors over $B$ to profunctors over $A$.  The identity profunctor of $C$ over $B$ is $C\times\mathbf{2}$, so the Beck-Chevalley condition for $\Pi_f$ tells us that this operation preserves identity profunctors.  Similarly, $f\times \mathbf{3}$ is also exponentiable, and a category over $B\times \mathbf{3}$ consists of three categories $C_0,C_1,C_2$ over $B$, three profunctors $H_{01} : C_0$ ⇸ $C_1$, $H_{12}: C_1$ ⇸ $C_2$ and $H_{02}:C_0 $⇸ $C_2$ along with a transformation $H_{01} \otimes_{C_1} H_{12} \to H_{02}$.  Thus $\Pi_f$ extends to a map on such data as well.  Repeating with $\mathbf{4}$, I believe we can show that $\Pi_f$ extends to a normal lax double functor from the double category $\mathrm{Prof}/B$ to the double category $\mathrm{Prof}/A$.

> Under what conditions on $f$ is this a *strong* double functor?  In other words, when does $\Pi_f$ preserve composites of profunctors up to isomorphism?

It could be that it is always strong, which would be the best possible answer, but I don't have any particular reason to expect that (but nor do I know any examples where it is not).